# Plotly.js x-axis cannot remove line

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm new to Plotly. and practising by creating a dummy line chart.  I have a problem removing the x-axis showline.  I have set it to false, used zeroline, and tried to make transparent using linecolor but still it remains.  Coincidentally, the y-axis works fine, as does showgrid for both axis's.

I have some inkling the issue may arise from the 'category' type used to show seasons '2017-18', '2018-19' etc but would appreciate confirmation (or a workaround) from someone more experienced with Plotly.  Thanks.

```
var bedford = {
x: ['2009-10', '2010-11', '2011-12', '2012-13', '2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19'],
y: [2812, 2654, 2828, 3051, 2261, 2496, 2611, 2515, 2530, 2527],
name: 'Bedford',
mode: 'lines+markers',
line: {
  color: 'rgb(128,191,255)',
  width: 2
  }
};

var birmingham = {
x: ['2009-10', '2010-11', '2011-12', '2012-13', '2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19'],
y: [975, 894, 881, 971, 947, 1098, 1046, 830, 800, 676],
name: 'Birmingham',
mode: 'lines+markers',
line: {
  color: 'rgb(230,0,0)',
  width: 2
  }
};

var data = [bedford, birmingham];

var layout = {
  title: 'Second Tier Clubs Average Attendances',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Season',
    type: 'category',
    showline: false,
    linewidth: 0
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Attendance',
    range: [0, 3500],
    showline: false,
    linewidth: 0
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('attendanceDiv', data, layout);
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it fixed your problem? By doing so, other users will know that the issue has been solved.

Comment: No problem schustischuster.  I am very new to Stackoverflow and just getting used to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set **yaxis: {zeroline: false}**, please have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xo3rvbg/2/

```
var data = [bedford, birmingham];

var layout = {
  title: 'Second Tier Clubs Average Attendances',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Season',
    type: 'category',
    zeroline: false,
    showline: false,
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Attendance',
    range: [0, 3500],
    zeroline: false,
    showline: false,
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('attendanceDiv', data, layout);
```

Comment: Thanks schustischuster - working fine now.  Nice, straightforward answer.  I had tried zeroline previously but for some reason was using 0 instead of false.